# PDF preview works in debug mode of flow but not when actually running without debug mode

Tags: lightning-web-components, csp

We have a flow that has a embeded lwc component within a flow screen that creates a preview of pdf file based on the base64 body received through integration.The pdf preview uses the logic explained [here](https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/base64ToPdf/base64ToPdf.js)  When i am trying to display the preview of the pdf inside the flow screen i get the below error

> Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "frame-src blob: https: mailto:
> https://api.appinium.com https://content.appinium.com
> https://az766683.vo.msecnd.net
> https://appiniumcontentcentralus.blob.core.windows.net
> https://appiniumcontenteastaus.blob.core.windows.net
> https://appiniumcontentwesteu.blob.core.windows.net
> https://upload.appinium.com https://util.appinium.com
> https://helpers.appinium.com  *.vf.force.com".

I read few posts and most this error due to CSP Trust Site which needs to be added but inspite of adding all the urls i still am not able to get the rendering and it remains blocked when running but it displays correctly when i run the flow in 'Debug mode'. Below are the two screenshots - one running in debug mode where the preview gets displayed properly and other when running in a normal mode in the app builder

Screen in debug mode where the pdf preview works correctly -
[image]

Flow in regular mode where pdf preview gives a error -
[image: ![enter image description here]

Any help on how we can have the preview working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried adding the remote site settings and CORS